# How to have the sum of withCount on the multiple relationships in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a basic three tables users and guests and posts

Also i have table named user_views:
to store unique users views of posts

```
post_id   user_id
1         10002
2         10003
3         10011
```

And another table named guest_views:
to store unique guests views of posts

```
post_id   guest_id
1         10002
2         10003
3         10011
```

In Post model i have:

```
public function user_views()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\PostUserView');
}

public function guest_views()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\PostGuestView');
}
```

In the following code get the correct results but with two different keys.

```
$posts = Post::all()
            ->withCount('user_views')
            ->withCount('guest_views')
```

I thought of merge user_views and guest_views then compute count as follow but the result only includes count of user_views

```
public function views()
{
    return $this->user_views()->unionAll($this->guest_views());
}
```

After you perform the following code

```
$posts = Post::all()
            ->withCount('views')
            ->withCount('user_views')
            ->withCount('guest_views')
```

I get this result

```
"views_count": 5, 
"user_views_count": 5,
"guest_views_count": 2,
```

The expected result for prevues example is:

```
"views_count": 7, 
"user_views_count": 5,
"guest_views_count": 2,
```

Also i try to use sql query as follow

```
public function views()
{
    return DB::raw("(select * from post_views) union all (select * from post_guest_views)");
}
```

But get

```
"Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression::getRelationExistenceCountQuery()"
```

So I'd like to get total number of views from all users and guest for each post.

Comment: I think I need to perform the following query:

`select posts.*, (select count(*) from `user_views` where `posts`.`id` = `user_views`.`post_id`) + (select count(*) from `guest_views` where `posts`.`id` = `guest_views`.`post_id`) , .... `

Answer (score 3):

In your **Post** model

```
public function user_views()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\PostUserView','user_id','id');
}

public function guest_views()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\PostGuestView','user_id','id');
}

public function views() 
{
   return $this->user_views()->unionAll($this->guest_views()); 
}
```

Now you can access

```
$posts = Post::withCount(['user_views','guest_views','views'])->get()
```

**Note**

> Every parameter that is specified in **withCount()** method, becomes
>   main object’s _count property. So in this case, we will have
>   $posts->guest_views_count,$posts->views_count and
>   $posts->user_views_count variables.

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: I get this exception :

"Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on integer"

Comment: when you got the error and which line you got please give me the exact error ?

Comment: when use `with('userCount')` i get above exception

Comment: do you have the `user_views` and `guest_views` function above

Comment: please tell  the unique key with `user` and `user_views` and `guest_views`

Comment: the primary key of user table is: id
the primary key of user_views table is pair of: (user_id, post_id) 
the primary key of guest_views table is pair of: (user_id, post_id)

Comment: I do not think the problem is in the primary key
The problem lies in calling `"with"` with a method that return an integer value

So when i execute
`Post :: with ('user_views')
        -> with ('guest_views')
        -> with ('views') 
        -> get ();`

I get the correct records without any problems, but i need to count of those tables.

Comment: Now will work correctly, but I want to be included in the query to get the number of times each posts is viewed.

Comment: please check this image to better understand 
https://imgur.com/1BAiTnO

Comment: don't worry you can use count in blade template as well it will give the same result

Comment: From the beginning I know that I can sum this two values from mobile app side, But I'm trying to build correct API and get the correct value of counter from this API.

Comment: ohh i got it now ok i will give you the correct answer after some time thanks

Comment: I'm waiting for you, Thanks very well

Comment: there is only way to do in laravel is `countWith` so i changed the answer  and hope this time answer is correct please check and let me know

Answer (score 0):

you can get number of  view counts using `join()`. Below is the example of code:-

```
$posts = Post::join('user_views as uv', function($q) {
    $q->on('uv.post_id', '=', 'posts.id');
})
->join('guest_views as gv', function($q) {
    $q->on('gv.post_id', '=', 'posts.id');
})
->selectRaw("posts.*, COUNT(uv.id) as user_views_count, COUNT(gv.id) guest_views_count, SUM(COUNT(uv.id) + COUNT(gv.id)) as views_count")
->groupBy("posts.id")
->get();
```

Try this.

Comment: I think the query is equivalent to the following :

`select posts.*, 
COUNT(uv.user_id) as user_views_count, 
COUNT(gv.user_id) as guest_views_count, 
COUNT(uv.user_id) + COUNT(gv.user_id) as views_count 

from `posts` 

inner join `user_views`   as `uv` on `uv`.`post_id` = `posts`.`id` 
inner join `guest_views` as `gv` on `gv`.`post_id` = `posts`.`id``

I think it needs a "group by" but also will not get me the right result

Answer (score 0):

You can use the collection method reduce as below:

```
$posts->reduce(function($carry,$item){
  return $carry+$item->user_views_count;
},0);
```

for more please check the reduce documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-reduce